# How to set PATH environment variable with Kubernetes env?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, environment-variables, containers, pipeline

I want to find a solution on how to set PATH  environment variable in a container that is running in a pod by concatenating a known path to it. Until now I have used:

> ```
> - name: PYTHONUSERBASE
>   value: /opt/python
> - name: PATH
>   value: /opt/python/bin:$(PATH)
> ```

I am calling this pod's yaml using Jenkins pipeline step:
yaml kubernetesPodTemplate(name: "${label}", binding: ['env': env])
and it fails with:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PATH for
> class: groovy.lang.Binding

I have also tried with:

> ```
> /opt/python/bin:\$(PATH)
> /opt/python/bin:${PATH} 
> /opt/python/bin:\\\\$PATH
> ```

but nothing seems to be working.
A little help will be much appreciated as I am still learning Kubernetes and I don't know if it has something that could ease my work in my case.

Thank you,
A.

```
 - name: PYTHONUSERBASE   
   value: /opt/python
 - name: PATH   
   value: /opt/python/bin:$(PATH)
```

Comment: You can use a configmap and use that in your deployment yaml file